# Sharing the datalab notebooks

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

As per i read, we can share cloud datalab notebooks either by downloading .pynb file and sharing that way or sharing the html link.
I have created a new folder under datalab_main and created new notebook .I have committed the file from the git repository source code and it got committed successfully.Now when i tried sharing the html way,the repository commits were not being reflecting for others in the same project(Have all permissions) and when they hit the html URL,its giving 404 since the folder I created was not created for other users.Can you please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the notebook was successfully committed, ask your team members to click on the following [link](https://console.cloud.google.com/code/develop/browse/default/master), select the correct branch in the drop down menu, then click the *Refresh* link in the right pane. The *Refresh* link is similar to a `git pull` command. The notebook should appear now.

If they're still having trouble, ask your team member to run a `git pull` command directly from a notebook in the parent folder. This should be a last resort as I expect the *Refresh* link will solve the issue.

To execute a `git pull` command, run either of the following

```
%%bash
git pull
```

or

```
!git pull
```